# How to update my grep utility on CentOS 5.6?

Tags: centos, package-management, grep

I'm using a CentOS 5.6 system. Since there is **[a bug](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8892/trouble-with-grep-o-regex)** in my version of grep. I want to upgrade to a new version. I tried to use yum to update(upgrade) it, but failed.

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/redhat-
redhat-lsb/     redhat-release  
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 5.6 (Final)
[root@localhost ~]# grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1

Copyright 1988, 1992-1999, 2000, 2001 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

[root@localhost ~]# yum update gerp
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.btte.net
 * extras: mirrors.btte.net
 * updates: mirrors.btte.net
base                                                                                                                           | 1.1 kB     00:00     
extras                                                                                                                         | 2.1 kB     00:00     
updates                                                                                                                        | 1.9 kB     00:00     
Setting up Update Process
No Match for argument: gerp
No package gerp available.
No Packages marked for Update
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Comment: You misspelled `grep` in your `yum update` above, which probably isn't helping.  But you should also be aware of RedHat's patching policy; they will never bump versions inside a given RHEL (and therefore CentOS), but they usually backport fixes.  Which particular grep bug are you concerned with?

Answer (score 1):

Does `yum update grep` help you? You had a typo in your copy-paste: `gerp`.

Also please note that RHEL/CentOS do only backport important security fixes and so on, and do not constantly update to latest and greatest version of any particular software.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a typo?

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum update ****gerp****
argument: gerp No package gerp available. No Packages marked for Update
```

You want **grep** instead of **gerp**